# Change method to use Promise.all in typescript

Tags: javascript, typescript, promise, protractor, rxjs

I have following method:

```
public static zoomInMap(times: number): void {

  for (let i = 0; i < times; i++) {
    let zoomInButton = element(by.css('#main > cc-map > div.google-map-base-  container-inner > div > div.gmnoprint.gm-bundled-control.gm-bundled-control-on-bottom > div:nth-child(1) > div > div:nth-child(1)'));
    zoomInButton.click();
    browser.sleep(Config.ZOOM_ANIMATION_TIMEOUT).then(() => {
    // console.log('Map Zoomed In');
   });
 }
```

}

I want to make it return a Promise . I want to use Promise.all
Like:

```
 public static zoomInMap(times: number): Promise<any> {

 return Promise.all( ? ) // ? I do not know how to do it
  for (let i = 0; i < times; i++) {
    let zoomInButton = element(by.css('#main > cc-map > div.google-map-base-container-inner > div > div.gmnoprint.gm-bundled-control.gm-bundled-control-on-bottom > div:nth-child(1) > div > div:nth-child(1)'));
    zoomInButton.click();
    browser.sleep(Config.ZOOM_ANIMATION_TIMEOUT).then(() => {
     // console.log('Map Zoomed In');
    });
  }
}
```

How should I rework the code to use Promise.all . Sorry for lame question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Gather up your promises in an array, then call `Promise.all` on the array and return the result, which is the aggregated promise:

```
public static zoomInMap(times: number): Promise {
  let promises = [];
  for (let i = 0; i < times; i++) {
    let zoomInButton = element(by.css('#main > cc-map > div.google-map-base-  container-inner > div > div.gmnoprint.gm-bundled-control.gm-bundled-control-on-bottom > div:nth-child(1) > div > div:nth-child(1)'));
    zoomInButton.click();
    promises.push(browser.sleep(Config.ZOOM_ANIMATION_TIMEOUT).then(() => {
        // You can do something here if you like, or remove the `then`
    }));
  }
  return Promise.all(promises);
}
```

I'm not big on TypeScript, you may have to adjust the declaration of the array. I've changed the return type of the function from `void` to `Promise`.

Answer (score 1):

Rather than using a loop, you could create an `Array` of size `times`. Then fill it with `map` :

```
public static zoomInMap(times: number): Promise<void> {
  return Promise.all(new Array(times).fill().map(() => {

    let zoomInButton = element(by.css('#main > cc-map > div.google-map-base-container-inner > div > div.gmnoprint.gm-bundled-control.gm-bundled-control-on-bottom > div:nth-child(1) > div > div:nth-child(1)'));
    zoomInButton.click();

    return browser.sleep(Config.ZOOM_ANIMATION_TIMEOUT).then(() => {
    // console.log('Map Zoomed In');
    });

  }));
}
```